# how to access my custom jsp taglib in STS 4.3?

Tags: spring, jsp, taglib

I have a Spring MVC web app whic I'm developing using the STS 4.3 as my IDE.

I decided to try my hand on custom JSP tag libraries.

These are the tutorial I'm following: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm and http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/ and http://blog.denevell.org/tomcat7-el-custom-function.html and many other links (too many to list but similar in content).

I have configured Tomcat7 as my testing server from with STS 4.3

I have created a new project in STS and called it "MyCustomUtilities".

**folder structure of MyCustomUtilities project**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoF4G.jpg

**source code for MyCustomUtilities.java**

```
package org.flinders.mycustomutilities;

import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class MyCustomUtilities {

    public static String StringToHTML(String inputString) {
        StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
        char[] inputChar = inputString.toCharArray();

        for (char c: inputChar) {
            returnString.append("&#").append((int) c).append(";");
        }

        return returnString.toString();

    }
}
```

**JSP snippet** (I've also tried <%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/MyCustomUtilities.tld" prefix="mine" %> but still getting error)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://localhost:8080/MyCustomUtilities.tld" prefix="mine" %>
```

Tomcat folder structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgiGb.jpg

I have created a system variable called "CLASSPATH" and it's pointing to the ROOT/WEB-INF (full path of course. just shorten it here).

here's my TLD file (unsure on what to put on the uri portion but I'm accessing my web app on localhost:8080 on my browser)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
    <uri>localhost:8080/MyCustomUtilities</uri>

    <function>
        <name>StringToHTML</name>
        <function-class>org.flinders.mycustomutilties.MyCustomUtilities</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String StringToHTML(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Any ideas on how can I setup/configured tomcat/STS so it can see my custom tag library? As I said above, I'm looked at various examples but they don't seem complete. thanks

Comment: Instead of `uri="WEB-INF/...` try `uri="/WEB-INF/...`

Comment: same error in STS ide. "Cannot find taglib descriptor for xxx".

Comment: make sure that the `.tld` file also exists under `work/catalina/.../WEB-INF`

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that the `<uri>` in the tld file is invalid

Comment: no WEB-INF folder under work or any of its subfolders. see link: http://i.imgur.com/AHJWHRj.jpg I think the uri in my TLD invalid too but I'm not sure what to put there. The examples I've seen doesn't really talk about the details on how the TLD is written. x.x